# asp.net form validation flow

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have an asp.net form (not MVC) with save button, after validation showing false and displaying the error, but the the logic still pass to save routine to continue doing save to database. I am not sure where to tell do not do save routine. Am I making sense?

click save button,
validate,
validation failed,
save button routine executed.

I think there must be something can pass to save button routine to tell it not to execute save to database right?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: WHY do people find it necessary to add [tag:asp-classic] to questions that clearly have nothing to do with the subject, and what's more, the poster is perfectly aware of the fact that [tag:asp-classic] has nothing to do with the subject?

Comment: This is pretty basic and you are definitely missing something while setting up validators. Anyways show us the code (aspx) at least.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to check [Page.IsValid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid(v=vs.110).aspx) before saving to database.

Comment: If the validation controls are set and working properly, one need not even check for this in code behind.